# Automatically select option (Radio) buttons based on condition

Tags: excel, vba

I have two groups of radio buttons.
[image]

One group for **transaction type** and another for **transaction number**.

Six transactions are allowed in a day. Three for withdrawals and three for deposits.

I am trying to auto select next radio button if one is used.

```vb
Sub OBWithdrawal_Click()

Dim OBWithdrawal, OBDeposit, OB1st, OB2nd, OB3rd As OptionButton

    'transaction type

Set OBWithdrawal = Sheet1.Shapes("OBWithdrawal").OLEFormat.Object
Set OBDeposit = Sheet1.Shapes("OBDeposit").OLEFormat.Object

    'transaction number

Set OB1st = Sheet1.Shapes("OB1st").OLEFormat.Object
Set OB2nd = Sheet1.Shapes("OB2nd").OLEFormat.Object
Set OB3rd = Sheet1.Shapes("OB3rd").OLEFormat.Object

If Sheet1.Range("G24").Value = "#NUM" Then
    OB1st.Value = True

    If Sheet1.Range("G24").Value = 1 Then
        OB2nd.Value = True

        If Sheet1.Range("G24").Value = 2 Then
            OB3rd.Value = True

            If Sheet1.Range("G24").Value = 3 Then
                OB1st.Value = False
                OB2nd.Value = False
                OB3rd.Value = False
                MsgBox "You have only 3 withdrawal are allowed in a single day." & vbNewLine & ""

            End If
        End If
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

I did not receive any error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** Always declare variables separately. If you declare them as `Dim OBWithdrawal, OBDeposit, OB1st, OB2nd, OB3rd As OptionButton`, then only the last one which is `OB3rd` will be declared as `OptionButton`. Rest will be declared as `Variant`

**2.** You can use a single `IF-ELSEIF-ENDIF` statement to handle all those criteria.

**3.** This procedure is for `Withdrawal`. Similarly, create for `Deposit`. Alternatively, you can create a common procedure for both and then use `Application.Caller` to identify which is the "calling" option button and then execute the relevant code.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub OBWithdrawal_Click()
    Dim OBWithdrawal As OptionButton
    Dim OB1st As OptionButton
    Dim OB2nd As OptionButton
    Dim OB3rd As OptionButton

    Set OBWithdrawal = Sheet1.Shapes("OBWithdrawal").OLEFormat.Object
    
    With Sheet1
        Set OB1st = .Shapes("OB1st").OLEFormat.Object
        Set OB2nd = .Shapes("OB2nd").OLEFormat.Object
        Set OB3rd = .Shapes("OB3rd").OLEFormat.Object

        If .Range("G24").Value = "#NUM" Then
            OB1st.Value = True
        ElseIf .Range("G24").Value = 1 Then
            OB2nd.Value = True
        ElseIf .Range("G24").Value = 2 Then
            OB3rd.Value = True
        ElseIf .Range("G24").Value = 3 Then
            OB1st.Value = False
            OB2nd.Value = False
            OB3rd.Value = False
            MsgBox "You have only 3 withdrawal are allowed in a single day." & vbNewLine & ""
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

This is the 3rd way that I was talking about. Assign this code to both the `Withdrawal` and `Deposit` button. This will work for both.

```
Option Explicit

Sub OBWithdrawalDeposit_Click()
    Dim OptBtn As OptionButton
    Dim OB1st As OptionButton
    Dim OB2nd As OptionButton
    Dim OB3rd As OptionButton
    Dim OptBtnName As String
    Dim TrnType As String
    
    OptBtnName = Application.Caller
    
    '~~> If Withdrawal was selected
    If OptBtnName = "OBWithdrawal" Then
        Set OptBtn = Sheet1.Shapes("OBWithdrawal").OLEFormat.Object
        TrnType = "Withdrawals"
    ElseIf OptBtnName = "OBDeposit" Then '<~~ If Deposit was selected
        Set OptBtn = Sheet1.Shapes("OBDeposit").OLEFormat.Object
        TrnType = "Deposits"
    Else
        MsgBox "This procedure was not called the right way"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    With Sheet1
        Set OB1st = .Shapes("OB1st").OLEFormat.Object
        Set OB2nd = .Shapes("OB2nd").OLEFormat.Object
        Set OB3rd = .Shapes("OB3rd").OLEFormat.Object

        If .Range("G24").Value = "#NUM" Then
            OB1st.Value = True
        ElseIf .Range("G24").Value = 1 Then
            OB2nd.Value = True
        ElseIf .Range("G24").Value = 2 Then
            OB3rd.Value = True
        ElseIf .Range("G24").Value = 3 Then
            OB1st.Value = False
            OB2nd.Value = False
            OB3rd.Value = False
            MsgBox "You are allowed only 3 " & TrnType & " in a single day."
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Very much Mr.  @SiddharthRout. you made my day. your first solution was awesome. second solution was also good and working fine. but Range("G24") only counts withdrawals.

Comment: `but Range("G24") only counts withdrawals.` You can handle that as well like I did with `TrnType` ;)

Comment: I think, I need another range like **Range("G25")** to count **deposits**. but how I mention this line to this code? 
I know, you already solved my problem.

Comment: **1.** Declare `Dim rngAddress As String` at the top. **2.** Below `TrnType = "Withdrawals"`, type `rngAddress = "G5"`. Similarly below `TrnType = "Deposits"`, assign the relevant cell address for deposit. **3.** Finally in the rest of the code, change `.Range("G24").Value` to `.Range(rngAddress).Value`

Comment: Thank you again Mr. @SiddharthRout. I was stuck in this problem for the last two days. You solved my problem in a moment. I am correcting your last comment a little bit. **1.** Declare **Dim rngAddress As String** at the top. **2.** Below **TrnType = "Withdrawals"**, type **rngAddress = Range("G24").Value**. Similarly below **TrnType = "Deposits"**, type **rngAddress = Range("G25").Value**. **3.** Finally in the rest of the code, replace **.Range("G24").Value** to **rngAddress**.

Comment: No No... Change `rngAddress = Range("G24").Value` to `rngAddress = "G24"` and `rngAddress = Range("G25").Value` to `rngAddress = "G25"`. Finally change `Range("G24").Value` to `Range(rngAddress).Value`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251487/discussion-between-prabhat-vishwas-and-siddharth-rout).

Comment: Nice worked perfectly for me. Tried this last night. Helps to learn when there is clear explanation.